# Finding most frequency number in array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

By using following I am able to find most frequently occurring integer in an array. But following code it will not work for few scenarios. How can I fix the code inside for loop? I want to enhance this approach only.

```
class FindingMostFrequencyOccur {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1};
        int M = 3; // Maximum Number in Array
        int result = findFrequency(M, A);
        System.out.println("Result "+result);
    }

    static int findFrequency(int M, int[] A) {
        int N = A.length;
        int[] count = new int[M + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
            count[i] = 0;
        int maxOccurence = 1;
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (count[A[i]] > 0) {
                int tmp = count[A[i]];
                if (tmp > maxOccurence) {
                    maxOccurence = tmp;
                    index = i;
                }
                count[A[i]] = tmp + 1;
            } else {
                count[A[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
        return A[index];
    }
}
```

Can you we improve in this line

```
if (count[A[i]] > 0) {
                    int tmp = count[A[i]];
                    if (tmp > maxOccurence) {
                        maxOccurence = tmp;
                        index = i;
                    }
                    count[A[i]] = tmp + 1;
                } else {
                    count[A[i]] = 1;
                }
```

Comment: What is M supposed to be?

Comment: M is maximum number in array

Comment: `solution(M, A)` should be `findFrequency(M, A)`

Answer (score 2):

To get the frequency of `m` in `a` use:

```
static int findFrequency(int m, int[] a) {
     return (int)IntStream.of(a).filter(i-> i==m).count();
}
```

To get a map of all frequencies in `a` use:

```
static Map<Integer, Integer> findFrequency(int[] a) {
     Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
     IntStream.of(a).distinct().forEach(i->{
            m.put(i, findFrequency(i,a));
     });
     return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this logic, you take each element of the array, and find the number of times it is repeated to the right of it, in the array. This is given by `local_frequency`. If this happens to be more than `max_frequency`, then this number at `arr[i]` is stored in `number`, and then `max_frequency` stores `local_frequency`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4};
    int result = findMostFrequent(arr);
    System.out.println(result + " is the most frequent number");
}

public static int findMostFrequent(int[] arr)
{
    int number = arr[0];
    int maxFrequency = 0;

    for(int i =0 ; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int local_frequency = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            local_frequency++;
        }

        if(local_frequency > maxFrequency)
        {
            number = arr[i];
            maxFrequency = local_frequency;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```